# Unable to mock dependency in fast api framework (python)

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, fastapi

I am not able to mock the function dependency in my test case:

Here is the function I am trying to test :

```
    async def get_items(
        cosmos: str = Depends(cosmos_query)
    ):
        print('Test my function')
        items = await cosmos("items")
        // do something with items

Here is my test case:

fake_items = [{
        "name": "Test",
        "desc": "Test"
    }]
    async def override_cosmos_query():
        print('override_cosmos_query')
        return json.dumps(fake_items)       
    
    
    
    
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_get_items():
        app.dependency_overrides[cosmos_query] = override_cosmos_query
        print('Unit Test')
        async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
            response = client.get("/api/items")
        print(response)
```

I am trying to set the dependency on cosmos_query function to return a list of "Item" object instead of calling the actual cosmos_query function in Helper class.

I am able to print 3 lines in following order but the test case fails with the error:

[image]

Comment: So what is the issue? What's the problem with your current code? What is `Item` defined as? And since you're awaiting your returned cosmos query, I'm guessing the function you're using as an override also should be defined as async?

Comment: Added more information to complete the question.

Comment: Your original dependency does _not_ return a string directly; it returns a function or an object that can be used to query the database. If you want to simulate the same thing, return `lambda x: "foo"` instead (i.e. a function that takes a single argument and returns a static value - replace `foo` with whatever you want it to return when called in your test function.)